# Removing a tuple of type (list, float) from an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, tuples

I have for example this array of lists, tuples, and floats:

```
myList = [([1, 2, 3], 5.0)
          ([4, 5, 6], 2.0)
          ([2, 1, 7], 1.0)]
```

How do I remove `([4, 5, 6], 2.0)` from the array, so that the array looks like this:

```
[([1, 2, 3], 5.0)
 ([2, 1, 7], 1.0)]
```

I have tried to do something like `myList.remove(list(zip([4, 5, 6], 2.0))`, but this way I get an error `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`.

Comment: What makes that the item you want to remove - is it just due to being the second element?  The one with the exact value `([4, 5, 6], 2.0)`?  The one that contains 2.0 as the float sub-element (or other such detail that you'd have to search the whole list for)?  All of those scenarios have entirely different answers!

Comment: I don't understand why there is difficulty. It doesn't matter what the elements contain; removing an element works the same way. Did you **actually** mean that the problem is to **find** the element? "I've been trying for a while with pop and remove but I keep getting errors" We can only help with errors that are actually shown to us - please[take an organized approach](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to finding the problem yourself first; if you're still stuck, read [mre] and show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message.

Comment: Yes - sorry, I should have been clearer. I have a list of these tuples, and in these tuples is (list, float). I want to remove some tuples in certain positions, but I can't seem to understand how to remove that specific tuple. What I've tried is doing remove(list(zip(known list, known float))), but I get the error that 'float' object is not iterable. I will edit my question to be clearer.

Comment: `myList.remove(([4, 5, 6], 2.0))` removes the item from the list

Comment: I figured it out! Yes, as you say hostingutilities, this works. I hadn't realized that the extra brackets were needed. Thanks!

Comment: Without the extra parenthesis you're calling `remove` with two parameters. With the extra parenthesis you now have a single parameter, the tuple. There are situations were you don't have to use parenthesis to create a tuple, but if you are unsure if the parenthesis are required or not, the safe bet is to just always use them.

Answer (score 0):

we are to remove the elements first occurence from the list whether it's list of tuples. We can easily handle this by list method named 'list.remove(value)' which takes the item that is to be removed. The code goes like this :

```
myList = [([1, 2, 3], 5.0),
          ([4, 5, 6], 2.0),
          ([2, 1, 7], 1.0)]
myList.remove(([4, 5, 6], 2.0))
print(myList)
```

I hope this must help you to get the problem
If It did then I have a request for you to please checkout my Youtube Channel Taprin Classes where I upload videos based on Python Tutorials.
Have a Good Day Ahead !